# Count all recent posts from user - doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count all the posts from the user, from the last hour. This is my code:

```
$all_user_recent_posts=mysql_query("select * from user_post where user_id=$userid and where post_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);");
$count_user_recent_posts=mysql_num_rows($all_user_recent_posts);
```

This code doesn't work(it has the value 0). But when I delete `and where post_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`, it does work,  but it show me ALL the post of the user, and not posts from the last hour. Code:

```
$all_user_recent_posts=mysql_query("select * from user_post where user_id=$userid;");
$count_user_recent_posts=mysql_num_rows($all_user_recent_posts);
```

Comment: Because there are no posts in an hour interval?

Comment: I post every few seconds :P

Comment: *ahem* `where user_id=$userid and where post_time` it's a syntax error. `where user_id=$userid and post_time` the where clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/where-optimizations.html uses ONE where, not multiple and seperated by `AND` or `OR`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php would have told you about it too. @jaldk

Comment: I would suspect that `mysql_num_rows()` is throwing an error, since `$all_user_recent_posts` is `false`.  If you're not seeing that, you may want to turn on error reporting and logging.  Additionally, you should always check if the SQL query is resulting in an error before trying to use the result.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  How can I upvote your second comment 300 times :P

Comment: @xQbert ah... that "one" counts enough for me *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: You certainly could have posted it as an answer.  Rep farming is ok in moderation :)

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @David True but now it got a downvote for the wiki I posted. Good thing huh? ;-) (wiki). and wiki has no rep gain/loss.

Comment: What is the column format for `post_time`?

Comment: also, if you want to count posts, why not use `COUNT()`? what is the present output you're getting now and could you provide us with the db schema/structure?

Comment: also, if there are any errors and you're not checking for them, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` should there be any. Other than that, there isn't much we can do to help you any further. We tried.

Answer (score 3):

As I stated in comments, and posting this as a **community wiki** because nothing should be gained from this in regards to rep points.

`where user_id=$userid and where post_time` it's a syntax error.

`where user_id=$userid and post_time` the `where` clause  uses ONE where, not multiple and seperated by `AND` or `OR`.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/where-optimizations.html

and error checking against your query would have told you about it too.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

and should also be checked against your query, should there be any there also.

Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Error reporting is an additional tool you can use.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Additionally, the `post_time` column must be a valid MySQL date type.

If you're trying to do math on a `varchar` type, then it won't work, or anything that isn't a valid date-related type.

Consult:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

It is unknown as to how you're using `mysql_num_rows()`.

The following two examples will react differently.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

and

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra **where** in your query
near

```
and where post_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Replace your with this

```
$all_user_recent_posts=mysql_query("select * from user_post where user_id=$userid and post_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);");
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: still give me 0...